# ¿Por qué se leen bien los datos de un fichero binario a partir del segundo intento?

Tags: c++

Tengo este código :

```
class PRUEBA
{
    public:
        int i;
        char c[100];
        ~PRUEBA();
};

#include "PRUEBA.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    PRUEBA prueba1;

    prueba1.i = 0;
    strcpy_s(prueba1.c, "A");

    std::ofstream out("Binario.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&prueba1), sizeof(prueba1));

    PRUEBA prueba2;
    std::ifstream in("Binario.bin", std::ios::binary);
    in.seekg(0);
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&prueba2), sizeof(prueba2));

    std::cout << " Prueba2.i = " << prueba2.i << std::endl;
    std::cout << " Prueba2.c = " << prueba2.c << std::endl;
    out.close();
    in.close();

    return 0;
}
```

La primera vez que lo ejecuto se muestran estos valores :

```
Prueba2.i = -858993460  
Prueba2.c = ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠...▄T(êT(
```

Pero la segunda y siguientes se cargan los valores correctos :

```
Prueba.i = 0;
Prueba.c = A;
```

Entiendo que al incluir el flag  ***std::ios::app*** en

```
std::ofstream out("Binario.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);
```

cada vez que se ejecuta el programa se mandan al fichero los datos y estos se ***añaden*** a los ya existentes, posicionándolos al final del fichero. Pero no entiendo por qué no se cargan bien la primera vez que se leen incluso aunque se indique que empieze a leer desde el principio con la instrucción ***in.seekg(0);***, que según espero haber entendido bien al leer aquí : [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/?kw=seekg][1] sirve para eso.

Otra cosa a destacar es que el programa ***sólo*** funciona al incluir dicho flag ***std::ios::app***. Si no lo incluyo siempre carga los datos basura.

El caso es que así funcionar funciona, pero si, por ejemplo hubiera que guardar una lista muy grande de objetos o un solo objeto pero enorme y cada vez hubiera que incluirlo al fichero el tamaño de éste aumentaría hasta quién sabe cuánto, lo que no es muy eficiente ¿verdad?.

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Hipótesis.

Seguramente se deba a que cuando haces `seekg` al inicio de `Binario.bin` para hacer la posterior lectura sobre `prueba2` el archivo aún no ha sido escrito y la lectura falla. Incluso puede suceder que el archivo no esté disponible puesto que abres un stream de lectura sin haber cerrado el de escritura sobre el mismo archivo.

Al fallar la lectura, `prueba2` no contiene valor si no que contiene la memoria que tuviera. Dado que `PRUEBA` carece de constructor, sus miembros no están inicializados y contienen *basura*, que es lo que se te muestra al imprimir su contenido.

#### ¿Qué hacer?

**Que el archivo esté disponible**.

Es tan fácil como comprobar el retorno de [`is_open`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/is_open).

**Comprueba la lectura**.

Comprueba que la lectura realizada por `in` ha sido correcta. De haber sido incorrecta la instrucción [`in.fail()`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail) devolverá falso. Los stream de archivo también son convertibles a `bool` siendo [su valor falso cuando ha fallado algo en su uso](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate).

**Cierra el archivo antes de volverlo a abrir**.

Para evitar fallos de lectura deberías cerrar el stream que estás escribiendo (`out`) antes de abrir otro apuntando al mismo archivo (`in`), cerrar el archivo fuerza un [*flusheo*](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush) del archivo, así que los cambios irán a parar a disco y estarán disponibles para la lectura.

**Proporciona un constructor a `PRUEBA`**.

Si inicializas los valores de las instancias de `PRUEBA` con valores predeterminados, te será más fácil ver que no ha sido modificado durante la lectura.

#### Propuesta.

Con los cambios propuestos [[tu código quedaría así]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/79ZIndhsS8OZPvoA):

```
// Si todo es publico, con una struct nos basta
struct PRUEBA
{
    int i;
    char c[100];
    PRUEBA() : i(0), c{} {}; // el constructor pone todos los datos a 0
};

int main()
{
    PRUEBA prueba1; // Todos los valores a 0, gracias al constructor
    std::strncpy(prueba1.c, "A", 2);

    std::ofstream out("Binario.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);

    if (out.is_open())
    {
        /* Los stream pueden convertirse a bool, si algo falla en una
          operacion su valor sera false. */
        if (out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&prueba1), sizeof(prueba1)))
        {
            std::cout << "Se escribio un dato correctamente\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Fallo al escribir\n";
        }
        /* Ya no necesitamos escribir más, cerramos el stream, esto provocara
           que los datos pendientes de ser escritos vayan a parar al archivo
           y estaran disponibles para su lectura */
        out.close();
    }

    PRUEBA prueba2; // Todos los valores a 0, gracias al constructor
    std::ifstream in("Binario.bin", std::ios::binary);
    in.seekg(0);

    if (in.is_open())
    {
        /* Los stream pueden convertirse a bool, si algo falla en una
          operacion su valor sera false. */
        if (in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&prueba2), sizeof(prueba2)))
        {
            std::cout << "Se leyo un dato correctamente\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Fallo al leer\n";
        }
        in.close();
    }

    std::cout << " Prueba2.i = " << prueba2.i << std::endl;
    std::cout << " Prueba2.c = " << prueba2.c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mecachis, nunca me doy cuenta de esos "pequeños" detalles como cerrar los archivos. Por alguna razón misteriosa siempre pienso que se "hace solo". Y muchas gracias por contestar tan rápido :).

Comment: Me tiraba un fallo C3867 en `if (out.is_open())` pero debía ser cosa de Visual Studio porque en CodeBlocks compila y funciona sin problemas.

Comment: Y en cuanto a lo del constructor, lo quité porque al incluir uno que inicializara el objeto con valores distintos de cero, por ejemplo `PRUEBA(int x, char a[])` no había forma de que cargara los datos correctamente. Me imagino que hay que utilizar uno digamos "vacío" que inicialize todas las variables a cero ¿verdad?.

Comment: @Battyhal Inicializar un arreglo estático en el constructor de un objeto merece una pregunta para si mismo; te animo a que abras una pregunta con esa duda ;)

Comment: @PaperBirdMasterOk, voy a ello.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando tu haces

```
out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&prueba1), sizeof(prueba1));
```

Estás escribiendo en el buffer de salida del fichero, pero eso no quiere decir que la información se vuelque instantáneamente en el fichero... eso lo puedes forzar con `out.flush()`.

Lo que está sucediendo entonces es lo siguiente:

Si **no** usas `std::ios::app`, al abrir el fichero para escritura se borra su contenido y el mismo se queda en blanco. Después escribes cierta información en el buffer asociado a dicho archivo pero el fichero sigue en blanco. Después intentas leer información y... sopresa!!! lees basura porque el fichero aun sigue vacío. Al cerrar `out` se vuelca lo que quede en el buffer de salida al fichero y es entonces cuando la información queda reflejada en el fichero.

Si **sí**  usas `std::ios::app` entonces no se resetea el contenido del fichero. Si el fichero no existiese entonces lo más seguro es que aun así acabes leyendo basura... pero si el archivo ya existía y tenía contenido entonces el lector será capaz de leer, al menos, esa información antigua.

**¿Soluciones?**

La más obvia es no tener un escritor y un lector trabajando sobre el mismo fichero. Cierra el escritor antes de abrir el lector y verás como todo funciona a la perfección.

Otra solución pasaría por forzar el volcado de datos al fichero mediante `out.flush()`, pero yo no recomendaría esta solución.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apunte eferion. ¿Por qué no recomiendas forzar el volcado con `out.flush()` ?.

Comment: @Battyhal Quizás me expliqué mal. No digo que usar `flush` sea mala práctica. Me refería a que tener dos sesiones del mismo fichero abiertas a la vez es algo complicado de utilizar y es propenso a errores